# How can I get the p.value of all regressions using lapply function

Tags: r, lapply, summary

I am using an example, with mtcars, to later use it in the analysis of my data. I can get a list of summaries and the coef function on each regressions. My question is how can I get the p.value of all regressions in a list using lapply function?

Here is my code

```
    library(data.table)
    regressions <- 
    data.table(mtcars)[, 
          .(Myregressions = lapply(.SD, function(x) summary(lm(mpg ~ x)))), 
          .SDcols = -1]

Regressions$MyRegressions
Regressions[, lapply(MyRegressions, coef)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the 'MyRegressions' and extract the column

```
regressions[, lapply(Myregressions, function(x) coef(x)[, "Pr(>|t|)"])]
```

If we need to extract only selected values

```
regressions[, list(lapply(Myregressions, function(x) {
      x1 <- coef(x)[, "Pr(>|t|)"]
      x1[x1 < 0.05]}))]$V1
```

Comment: Thanks for this! When I use this solution I get p.value<0.05 `Regresiones[, lapply(Lm, function(x) coef(x)[, "Pr(>|t|)"])] [2:3] < 0.05`. How to extract only TRUE regressions?

Comment: @Pablo sure, can you please share the link

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60817436/how-can-i-do-3064-regressions-using-the-lapply-function)

Comment: What I can do? can i delete the answer?