# How can I do 3064 regressions using the lapply function

Tags: r, linear-regression, lapply

Hi i am starting to use r and am stuck on analyzing my data. I have a dataframe that has 157 columns. Column 1 is the dependent variable and from column 2 to 157 they are the independent variables, but from column 2 to column 79 it is a type of independent variable (n = 78) and from 80 to 157 another type (n = 78). I want to perform (78 x 78 = 6084) multiple linear regressions leaving the first independent variable of the model fixed one at a time, from columns 2 to 79. I can fix the independent variable and do the regressions separately like this

```
lm(Grassland$column1 ~ Grassland$column2 +  x)
lm(Grassland$column1 ~ Grassland$column3 +  x)

lm(Grassland$column1 ~ Grassland$column79 +  x)
```

My question is how can I do the 3064 regressions, writing a single code and extracting only the regressions whose p-value <0.05, eliminating the non-significant regressions?

Here is my code

```
library(data.table)

Regressions <- 
data.table(Grassland)[, 
                      .(Lm = lapply(.SD, function(x) summary(lm(Grassland$column1 ~ Grassland$column2 + x)))), .SDcols = 80:157]

Regressions[, lapply(Lm, function(x) coef(x)[, "Pr(>|t|)"])] [2:3] < 0.05
```

Answer (score 0):

One, `data.table` isn't necessarily going to help you here, it works fine in an external `lapply`. First we generate the formulas programmatically (here I'll use most of `mtcars`), then we apply the formula onto the data.

```r
paste("mpg ~", setdiff(names(mtcars), "mpg"))
#  [1] "mpg ~ cyl"  "mpg ~ disp" "mpg ~ hp"   "mpg ~ drat" "mpg ~ wt"   "mpg ~ qsec" "mpg ~ vs"  
#  [8] "mpg ~ am"   "mpg ~ gear" "mpg ~ carb"

regressions <- lapply(paste("mpg ~", setdiff(names(mtcars), "mpg")),
                      function(frm) lm(as.formula(frm), data=mtcars))

regressions[1:2]
# [[1]]
# Call:
# lm(formula = as.formula(frm), data = mtcars)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)          cyl  
#      37.885       -2.876  
# [[2]]
# Call:
# lm(formula = as.formula(frm), data = mtcars)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)         disp  
#    29.59985     -0.04122
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `reformulate` to create a formula and then apply the `lm`

```
lapply(setdiff(names(mtcars), "mpg"), function(x) 
        lm(reformulate(x, "mpg"), data = mtcars))
```